# List in inspector not updating correctly. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an inventory system, there´s this list that holds an item and an amount. If the list is not showing in the inspector, it updates nicely, but if the list is in the inspector, then Unity shows me this message

> type is not a supported string value
>
>  UnityEditor.RetainedMode:UpdateSchedulers ()

[image]

Here´s is my inventory script

```
public class SO_Inventory : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<InventoryItem> ItemsInInventory;
    public int AvailableSlots = 9;

    public void UpdateInventory()
    {
        int randomNumber = Random.Range(0, GameAssets.instance.Items.Length);

        InventoryItem itemToAdd = new InventoryItem
        {
            Item = GameAssets.instance.Items[randomNumber],
            Amount = 3
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < ItemsInInventory.Count; i++)
        {
            if (itemToAdd.Item == ItemsInInventory[i].Item)
            {
                int spaceAvailable = itemToAdd.Item.MaxStack - ItemsInInventory[i].Amount;

                if (spaceAvailable > 0)
                {
                    int amountToAdd = Mathf.Min(itemToAdd.Amount, spaceAvailable);
                    ItemsInInventory[i].Amount += amountToAdd;
                    itemToAdd.Amount -= amountToAdd;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        if (itemToAdd.Amount > 0 && ItemsInInventory.Count < AvailableSlots)
        {
            ItemsInInventory.Add(itemToAdd);
        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class InventoryItem
    {
        public ItemObject Item;
        public int Amount;
    }
}
```

And here's the script of my items

```
    public ItemObject[] Items;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.delayCall += () =>
        {
            AssignItemIDs();
        };
    }

    private void AssignItemIDs()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++)
        {
            Items[i].ItemID = i;
        }
    }
#endif
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ItemObject
{
    public int ItemID;
    public string ItemName;
    [Range(1, 64)] public int MaxStack = 8;
}
```

I´ve played with the inventory script, but nothing seems to do the trick

Comment: Please take some time to ensure this is really a [mre]. For example, does the error go away when you remove the `for` loop inside of `AssignItemIds`? If it does, then you can remove it from the example code shown here, as the problem must lie elsewhere. You should do this with every piece of the code until you have a [mre]. You doing this once will save time that each person interested in helping would have to do individually for themselves.

Comment: I can't seem to find where you are initializing the List. Have you left that part out?

Comment: @RyanGray as it is serilazed into the Inspector the list will be automatically be initilaized by the Serializer

Comment: Do you have custom editor/propertydrawer scripts for some of the types? Also in general if you modify fields via script you want to make sure to `EditorUtility.SetDirty` according objects(s) so they are properly saved

Comment: @derHugo no, I don´t have any custom editor script.

Comment: @derHugo I understand that, though the author stated that it was working fine when it was NOT being shown in the inspector. How does that work? Maybe I should be posting a new question xD

Comment: @RyanGray as said the list is initialized by the serializer ... so basically everytime Unity loads the asset from a YAML file and instantiates the according c# class instance - Unity treats lists and arrays special there and never leaves them at null but empty for both serialization and deserialization - the error OP sees is not a NullReference issue but an internal issue .. still not sure what it is but it is not related to something not being initialized

Comment: @derHugo I don't think you've understood my question nor my reason behind asking it. Let's leave it though as I don't want to clutter this post with any more unrelated blabber.

Comment: OP, I actually have seen this error message before ... but those where issues related to e.g. FBX files and custom importers or custom Inspector scripts trying to use the wrong `SerializedProperty.XYZValue` .. it doesn't happen for me with your code so I suppose it is related to something else